# Remove element from list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

This seems to a variation on many topics on SE, but I haven't seen one specifically addressing the problem I'm having. I have a list of lists:

```
mylist <- list(list(`1` = 2:3, `2` = 4:5, `3` = 6:7, `4` = 8:10), list(
    `1` = 11:12, `2` = 13:14, `3` = 15:16, `4` = 17:18, `5` = 19:20, 
    `6` = 21:22), list(`1` = 23:24))
```

I would like to remove any *subelements* in the inner level that are contained in some other vector. For example if the elements to be removed are `c(4,5,19,20,23,24)`, then I would expect the output:

```
list(list(`1` = 2:3, `3` = 6:7, `4` = 8:10), list(
    `1` = 11:12, `2` = 13:14, `3` = 15:16, `4` = 17:18, 
    `6` = 21:22))
```

Removing the names would be ok as well. I've tried many things including:

```
removeListElem <- function(inlist,elem_remove){
  lapply(inlist,setdiff,elem_remove)
}

lapply(mylist,function(x) removeListElem(x,c(4,5,19,20,23,24)))
```

But it produces the output

```
list(list(`1` = 2:3, `2` = integer(0), `3` = 6:7, `4` = 8:10), 
    list(`1` = 11:12, `2` = 13:14, `3` = 15:16, `4` = 17:18, 
        `5` = integer(0), `6` = 21:22), list(`1` = integer(0)))
```

which I can then filter out for `integer(0)`.

Is there a *clean* and *efficient* (not doing nested lapply's) solution to removing a given set of elements in a list of lists?

Comment: Seems like you need to modify `removeListElem` to not just use `setdiff` but also do the filtering of `integer(0)`. Changing the body to `outlist = lapply(inlist,setdiff,elem_remove); outlist[lengths(outlist) > 0]` seems like it would work.

Comment: ```lapply(l, function(i) Filter(function(x) any(x != 0), i))```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't phrase my post properly. I'm able to filter out the `integer(0)` using a similar code as what @Gregor posted. However, I'm wondering if I can make this more efficient and not involve nested `lapply`s

Comment: When your input is nested, your solution will need to be nested too.

Comment: So there is no way around the nested `lapply`s? Just curious.

Comment: Sure, you could use nested for loops, or recursion, but the core concept is essentially the same. The way around would be to flatten your data structure so there isn't nesting.

Comment: I initially had my list flattened, but realized I need that extra level to for other book-keeping in my code. Thanks for your input.

Comment: E.g., instead of lists nested `n` deep, you could have a data frame where you have `n` columns giving ids, and a single value column. Then the code would be a simple subset of the data frame, `df[!df$value  %in% c(4,5,19,20,23,24), ]`

Comment: Adding to @Gregor 's comment about working with it as a data frame, you could then split it back into a list (or list of lists) after you do that subsetting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can incorporate the clean-up of inner lists into your function:

```
removeListElem <- function(inlist,elem_remove){
  outlist = lapply(inlist,setdiff,elem_remove)
  outlist[lengths(outlist) > 0]
}
```

This takes care of the `integer(0)`s, but still gives an empty list in the result:

```
result = lapply(mylist,function(x) removeListElem(x,c(4,5,19,20,23,24)))
result
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$`1`
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[1]]$`3`
# [1] 6 7
# 
# [[1]]$`4`
# [1]  8  9 10
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$`1`
# [1] 11 12
# 
# [[2]]$`2`
# [1] 13 14
# 
# [[2]]$`3`
# [1] 15 16
# 
# [[2]]$`4`
# [1] 17 18
# 
# [[2]]$`6`
# [1] 21 22
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# named list()
```

So we can clean up the result in a similar way:

```
result[lengths(result) > 0]
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$`1`
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[1]]$`3`
# [1] 6 7
# 
# [[1]]$`4`
# [1]  8  9 10
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$`1`
# [1] 11 12
# 
# [[2]]$`2`
# [1] 13 14
# 
# [[2]]$`3`
# [1] 15 16
# 
# [[2]]$`4`
# [1] 17 18
# 
# [[2]]$`6`
# [1] 21 22
```

This uses a nested `lapply`, just like your attempt. We can, of course, package it all into a function:

```
removeListElemComplete = function(inlist, elem_remove) {
  outlist = lapply(inlist, removeListElem, elem_remove = elem_remove)
  outlist[lengths(outlist) > 0]
}

removeListElemComplete(mylist, c(4,5,19,20,23,24))
# [[1]]
# [[1]]$`1`
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[1]]$`3`
# [1] 6 7
# 
# [[1]]$`4`
# [1]  8  9 10
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$`1`
# [1] 11 12
# 
# [[2]]$`2`
# [1] 13 14
# 
# [[2]]$`3`
# [1] 15 16
# 
# [[2]]$`4`
# [1] 17 18
# 
# [[2]]$`6`
# [1] 21 22
```